# Looking for a BackupAgent (for a sqlite database) example

Tags: android, sqlite, android-backup-service

I see several examples here, but none speak to backing up SQLite databases specifically, does anyone have a sample of doing this?
http://www.microdu.com/docs/guide/topics/data/backup.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android backup/restore: how to backup an internal database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282936/android-backup-restore-how-to-backup-an-internal-database)

Comment: Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12457955/810368

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282936/android-backup-restore-how-to-backup-an-internal-database) which gives an answer on how to backup your SQLite database so that it will be restored if someone installs it on a new phone (using Google's BackupAgent).

On the other hand, if you want to backup the database yourself, then you could copy it to your SD card as seen done in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995320/how-to-backup-database-file-to-sdcard-on-android).