# Examples of application, used Android Backup Services

Tags: android, android-backup-service

Do you know of any Android applications (open source, if it's possible), which uses the [Android Backup Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html)?

I need examples of how the Backup Service can be used in real applications.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a list of some open-sourced apps with Android Backup implemented:

- **Triple Solitaire** ([github sources](https://github.com/ianhanniballake/TripleSolitaire), [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.github.triplesolitaire))
- **KTodo** ([github sources](https://github.com/eprst/KTodo), [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kos.ktodo))
- **Penroser** ([github sources](https://github.com/JesusFreke/Penroser), [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jf.Penroser))
- **SeriesGuide Show Manager** ([github sources](https://github.com/UweTrottmann/SeriesGuide), [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.battlelancer.seriesguide))
- **ServiceDroid** ([github sources](https://github.com/seanmonstar/ServiceDroid), [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.monstarlab.servicedroid))
- **Awful** ([github sources](https://github.com/Geekner/Something-Awful-Android), [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ferg.awful))
- **ConnectBot**, Sage-Mobile-Calc ([github sources](https://github.com/mvcisback/Sage-Mobile-Calc), [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.connectbot))
- **Headphone SMS**, as mentioned by @CodeChimp above ([github sources](https://github.com/smike/headphonesms), [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smike.headphonesms))
- **Dragon, Fly! Free** (without source code, only Google Play [link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lsgvgames.slideandfly))
- **sms-backup-plus**, only [source code](https://github.com/jberkel/sms-backup-plus)

Answer (score 2):

A search of GitHub reveals quiet a few.

Here's one I found that also has a favourable review within Play Store.

[Headphone SMS Source Link](https://github.com/smike/headphonesms)

[Headphone SMS Play Store Link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smike.headphonesms)