# Anybody has Small Android project with a simple db?

Tags: java, android, mobile

I have been working on Android application, did a lot of research on connecting it with sqlite, but it never works. does any body have any small android project with one or two tables based db? i need source code, it will be helpful to understand for me.

Comment: Android Tutorial has two(!) - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db look at the end of the section.

Answer (score 1):

[The notepad tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html) is a decent introduction to using a database in an Android app.

Comment: Hi, the application works perfectly, but i am finding database named "data" but there is no file of this name anywhere, even not in assets, application is saving file nicely, but where it is saving, where the db is, lol its a mystery, how can i access it, please let me know.

Comment: (Please upvote and accept when appropriate.)  The database will be in the /data/data/YOUR.APP.PACKAGE/databases/ directory.  You'll not usually access it with file IO.

Comment: I cannot access it from sqlite browser, as i think i cannot open its db file on computer, because there is no data folder or databases directory.

Comment: (Please upvote and accept when appropriate.)  Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995320/how-to-backup-database-file-to-sdcard-on-android

Comment: thanks, nice link, but it is about virtual database which you cannot touch on pc, but i saw a tutorial, in which there was a way to access it and edit it with sqlite browser, to place db in assets bla bla, but this db is completely virtual, is there any way to open it on pc,