# Simple export and import of a SQLite database on Android

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I am trying to implement a simple `SQLite` export/import for backup purposes. Export is just a matter of storing a copy of the raw `current.db` file. What I want to do for import is to just delete the old `current.db` file and rename the `imported.db` file to `current.db`. Is this possible? When I try this solution, I get the following error:

```
06-30 13:33:38.831: ERROR/SQLiteOpenHelper(23570):
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseCorruptException: error code 11: database disk image is malformed
```

If I look at the raw database file in a `SQLite` browser it looks fine.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

I use this code in the `SQLiteOpenHelper` in one of my applications to import a database file.

EDIT:  I pasted my `FileUtils.copyFile()` method into the question.

**SQLiteOpenHelper**

```
public static String DB_FILEPATH = "/data/data/{package_name}/databases/database.db";

/**
 * Copies the database file at the specified location over the current
 * internal application database.
 * */
public boolean importDatabase(String dbPath) throws IOException {

    // Close the SQLiteOpenHelper so it will commit the created empty
    // database to internal storage.
    close();
    File newDb = new File(dbPath);
    File oldDb = new File(DB_FILEPATH);
    if (newDb.exists()) {
        FileUtils.copyFile(new FileInputStream(newDb), new FileOutputStream(oldDb));
        // Access the copied database so SQLiteHelper will cache it and mark
        // it as created.
        getWritableDatabase().close();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**FileUtils**

```
public class FileUtils {
    /**
     * Creates the specified <code>toFile</code> as a byte for byte copy of the
     * <code>fromFile</code>. If <code>toFile</code> already exists, then it
     * will be replaced with a copy of <code>fromFile</code>. The name and path
     * of <code>toFile</code> will be that of <code>toFile</code>.<br/>
     * <br/>
     * <i> Note: <code>fromFile</code> and <code>toFile</code> will be closed by
     * this function.</i>
     * 
     * @param fromFile
     *            - FileInputStream for the file to copy from.
     * @param toFile
     *            - FileInputStream for the file to copy to.
     */
    public static void copyFile(FileInputStream fromFile, FileOutputStream toFile) throws IOException {
        FileChannel fromChannel = null;
        FileChannel toChannel = null;
        try {
            fromChannel = fromFile.getChannel();
            toChannel = toFile.getChannel();
            fromChannel.transferTo(0, fromChannel.size(), toChannel);
        } finally {
            try {
                if (fromChannel != null) {
                    fromChannel.close();
                }
            } finally {
                if (toChannel != null) {
                    toChannel.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to delete the old database file if necessary.

Comment: Remember to up-vote answers you like, helps the community know which ones are good and which are junk.

Comment: The answer above by Austyn worked for me as well. One thing to note that is not noted here, is the use of String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/{appName}/"; to set the write path on the SD card.

Comment: That makes sense.  This is some good advice.  I actually do it inside my own application, but only included a string literal as a placeholder in this demo code.

Comment: @AustynMahoney: Will that work on non-rooted device ?

Comment: It used to. I have no idea with the new SD card changes made in 4.4.

Comment: what if I wanna to import some rows without wiping out existing db content?

Comment: Sorry but that is not related to this question, you will have to search for another answer.

Comment: for the path to the db: `context.getDatabasePath("db_filename")`

Comment: OK how does this make any sense? Your "fromFile" is associated with "newDB".  Then the "toFile" is associated with the "oldDB". So you are outputting to an old file and inputting from a new file? Did you purposefully screw up the variable names or was this an accident because it caused me great confusion for quite a while since I am unfamiliar with this topic which is why I looked on here for help. Every time I need help, people who post code on here make things 10 times more confusing than they do help...seriously

Comment: Please can someone help me use this code in my application I am new to all of this and any help will be appreciated. I have copied the code and I have also created the options of import and export of my database in my preferences list. What should I do to link it together?

Answer (score 40):

This is a simple method to export the database to a folder named backup folder you can name it as you want and a simple method to import the database from the same folder a

```
    public class ExportImportDB extends Activity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//creating a new folder for the database to be backuped to
            File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Exam Creator");

               if(!direct.exists())
                {
                    if(direct.mkdir()) 
                      {
                       //directory is created;
                      }

                }
            exportDB();
            importDB();

        }
    //importing database
        private void importDB() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {
                File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                File data  = Environment.getDataDirectory();

                if (sd.canWrite()) {
                    String  currentDBPath= "//data//" + "PackageName"
                            + "//databases//" + "DatabaseName";
                    String backupDBPath  = "/BackupFolder/DatabaseName";
                    File  backupDB= new File(data, currentDBPath);
                    File currentDB  = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

                    FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                    FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                    dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                    src.close();
                    dst.close();
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), backupDB.toString(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();

            }
        }
    //exporting database 
        private void exportDB() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {
                File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

                if (sd.canWrite()) {
                    String  currentDBPath= "//data//" + "PackageName"
                            + "//databases//" + "DatabaseName";
                    String backupDBPath  = "/BackupFolder/DatabaseName";
                    File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
                    File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

                    FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                    FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                    dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                    src.close();
                    dst.close();
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), backupDB.toString(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();

            }
        }

    }
```

Dont forget to add this permission to proceed it

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" >
    </uses-permission>
```

Enjoy

Comment: somehow the importDB and exportDB procedures are exactly identical?

Comment: Wrong: if you look closely, the 'currentDB' variable reffers to the data folder file in importDB, and the sd folder in exportDB.

Comment: one more question, how do you implement it with a click of a button on android.

Comment: What happens if the database file changes during the copy procedure?

Comment: Be careful with that implementation. It has got a memory leak in any error case during database export. The reason is that both streams (FileInputStream and FileOutputStream) are not closed inside a finally.

Comment: This is a sloppy example, I say that because IT IS a useful example but will require the programmer to make changes to the code in order for the code to operate properly. To make these changes you must already be very familiar with Java and FILE methods and FILE STREAM methods. Be Careful

Answer (score 4):

To export db rather it is SQLITE or ROOM:

Firstly, add this permission in AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Secondly, we drive to code the db functions:

```
private void exportDB() {
    try {
        File dbFile = new File(this.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).getAbsolutePath());
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(dbFile);

        String outFileName = DirectoryName + File.separator +
                DATABASE_NAME + ".db";

        // Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        // Transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        // Close the streams
        output.flush();
        output.close();
        fis.close();


    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("dbBackup:", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

***Create Folder on Daily basis with name of folder is Current date:***

```
public void createBackup() {

    sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("dbBackUp", MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = sharedPref.edit();

    String dt = sharedPref.getString("dt", new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy").format(new Date()));

    if (dt != new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy").format(new Date())) {
        editor.putString("dt", new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy").format(new Date()));

        editor.commit();
    }

    File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "BackupDBs");
    boolean success = true;
    if (!folder.exists()) {
        success = folder.mkdirs();
    }
    if (success) {

        DirectoryName = folder.getPath() + File.separator + sharedPref.getString("dt", "");
        folder = new File(DirectoryName);
        if (!folder.exists()) {
            success = folder.mkdirs();
        }
        if (success) {
            exportDB();
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Not create folder", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

---

> Assign the DATABASE_NAME without .db extension and its data type is string

Answer (score 1):

**Import and Export of a SQLite database on Android**

Here is my function for export database into device storage

```
private void exportDB(){
    String DatabaseName = "Sycrypter.db";
    File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
    FileChannel source=null;
    FileChannel destination=null;
    String currentDBPath = "/data/"+ "com.synnlabz.sycryptr" +"/databases/"+DatabaseName ;
    String backupDBPath = SAMPLE_DB_NAME;
    File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
    File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);
    try {
        source = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
        destination = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
        destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
        source.close();
        destination.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Your Database is Exported !!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here is my function for import database from device storage into android application

```
private void importDB(){
    String dir=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    File sd = new File(dir);
    File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
    FileChannel source = null;
    FileChannel destination = null;
    String backupDBPath = "/data/com.synnlabz.sycryptr/databases/Sycrypter.db";
    String currentDBPath = "Sycrypter.db";
    File currentDB = new File(sd, currentDBPath);
    File backupDB = new File(data, backupDBPath);

    try {
        source = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
        destination = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
        destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
        source.close();
        destination.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Your Database is Imported !!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want this in kotlin . And perfectly working

```
 private fun exportDbFile() {

    try {

        //Existing DB Path
        val DB_PATH = "/data/packagename/databases/mydb.db"
        val DATA_DIRECTORY = Environment.getDataDirectory()
        val INITIAL_DB_PATH = File(DATA_DIRECTORY, DB_PATH)

        //COPY DB PATH
        val EXTERNAL_DIRECTORY: File = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        val COPY_DB = "/mynewfolder/mydb.db"
        val COPY_DB_PATH = File(EXTERNAL_DIRECTORY, COPY_DB)

        File(COPY_DB_PATH.parent!!).mkdirs()
        val srcChannel = FileInputStream(INITIAL_DB_PATH).channel

        val dstChannel = FileOutputStream(COPY_DB_PATH).channel
        dstChannel.transferFrom(srcChannel,0,srcChannel.size())
        srcChannel.close()
        dstChannel.close()

    } catch (excep: Exception) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"ERROR IN COPY $excep",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        Log.e("FILECOPYERROR>>>>",excep.toString())
        excep.printStackTrace()
    }

}
```

Comment: it gives me an error that cant find such file or directory