# Download custom .sqlite file and use in Android app during runtime

Tags: android

My application uses a database which it gets as a .sqlite file from a webserver at runtime. This database can change, hence the need to get it at runtime. I have seen this link -http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/ but it assumes that we are preloading the application with the database. 
How do I download this file and use it in Android at runtime?

Comment: You can download the file and import it into the database: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6540906/android-simple-export-import-of-sqlite-database

Comment: Is this .sqlite file a script to populate a db, or the actual db?

Comment: @Jack - This is the actual DB itself. The thing is, this file is not an Android DB with the android-metadata table or the primary key name set to _id. Would it still work if I imported it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see this [link](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-download-fileimage-url-your-device) for an explanation on how to download a file from the internet. It uses an image, but its the same process for any file.

After that you can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6540906/android-simple-export-import-of-sqlite-database) question which shows how to import the file (linked by Peter Knego).