# Importing SQLite Database from External SD card

Tags: android, import, android-sqlite

Trying to implement import and export feature in my application.Exporting is just copying of file in to the sd card. which i have done but importing is bit problematic. As importing should delete the previous rather the current database i am using and load the previous one.
I have gone through various post on this site regarding importing of sqlite database from sd card in application.[Importing database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6540906/android-simple-export-import-of-sqlite-database/6542214#6542214),here there is an answer but i want to know when this method is to be called .? Or any other solution for this. would be really appreciated !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel this [link](http://androidgenuine.com/?tag=save-database-to-sdcard-android) will help you to find a solution basically you have to check whether you have included the permission in your manifest file to read and write external storage Device then follow the tutorial.

Comment: I think sankettt needs a response to the question - when to import/export but not how.

Comment: I am open to new solutions.. I have a custom preference page where i have two images on which i would import and export database so when to import and export is not a question i was like when i would call the method which was mentioned as answer in the link. But i am finding the solution provided by deepak is going to help me trying that part only.!

Comment: thanks sankettt hope it helps I will try to answer if any more clarification is required :)

Comment: @DeepakSamuelRajan done.. and voted for ur answer.. i do need help for other questions so can you help me if possible i have posted some questions so can u check those question ?

Comment: link not working @DeepakSamuelRajan . Please refer another link.

Answer (score 0):

Refer [this.](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper/). Using this you can club your db (.sqlite) in zip folder inside assests.
On installation it will unzip that & create the databse from your .sqlite file.