# Android Exporting of SQLite database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, permissions

i am trying to export the SQLite database from my application so that i could do a Export/Import feature for my application.

I am using the example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13644963/android-sqlite-database-exporting?rq=1) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6540906/android-simple-export-import-of-sqlite-database/6542214#6542214) for attempting to export the **SQLite database (/data/data/com.example.worldcountriesbooks/databases/group.db)** out of the Android device (Samsung Galaxy Note), Android 4.0.3 but i keep getting this error

```
12-14 00:56:33.722: I/Failed(14850): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.example.worldcountriesbooks/databases/group.db: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

I have also attempted to add the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` & `WRITE_MEDIA_STORAGE` into the manifest file but it doesn't work. I am able to browse to the actual file on my Android device as it is rooted but i can't read it with my application. Any idea why?

Sample code:

```
    try {
        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

        if (sd.canWrite()) {
            String currentDBPath = "//data//com.example.worldcountriesbooks/databases//group.db";
            String backupDBPath = "//mnt//sdcard//database.db";
            File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
            File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

            FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
            FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
            dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
            src.close();
            dst.close();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), backupDB.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If the file is in internal memory, Your app can read only from a special folder in internal memory. The path to that folder is returned by:

```
getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()
```

In your case it would be something like:

```
String path= this.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "databases" + File.separator + "group.db";
```

you can read it with `openFileInput()`.

More info:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Comment: so there's no way i can copy out the sqlite database from my application?

Comment: yes, i am already trying to write it to my sd card, but it can't even open the `/data/data` internal database to write to the sd card