# import/export to android sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

Ive seen a few posts on how to import and export a database in android and i found these code, but i cant seem to make it work. I get the error java.io.filenotfoundexception /storage/sdcard0/BackupFolder/DatabaseName:open failed ENOENT (no such file or directory). Ive changed a few things but i still get no file found exception

here is my export:

```
private void exportDB() {
        try {
             db.open();
             File newFile = new File("/sdcard/myexport");
            InputStream input = new FileInputStream(
            "/data/data/com.example.mycarfuel/data

bases/MyDatabase");

                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int length;
                while ((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    output.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }
                output.flush();
                output.close();
                input.close();
                db.close();

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
}
```

and my import:

```
private void importDB() {
        try {
            File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

            if (sd.canWrite()) {
                String currentDBPath = "//data//" + "PackageName"
                        + "//databases//" + "DatabaseName";
                    String backupDBPath = "/BackupFolder/DatabaseName

";
                File backupDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
                File currentDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

                FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                src.close();
                dst.close();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), backupDB.toString(),


Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Follow [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6542214/2345913)

Comment: ive seen this post. the second reply is the where ive copied my code from, the first reply only says about import not export

Comment: Please check this link, it can resolve this problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6540906/simple-export-and-import-of-a-sqlite-database-on-android

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**SQlite database to our local file system**-

Function declaration-

```
        try {
            backupDatabase();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Function defined-

```
public static void backupDatabase() throws IOException {
        //Open your local db as the input stream
        String inFileName = "/data/data/com.myapp.main/databases/MYDB";
        File dbFile = new File(inFileName);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(dbFile);

        String outFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/MYDB";
        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = fis.read(buffer))>0){
            output.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        //Close the streams
        output.flush();
        output.close();
        fis.close();
    }
```

Comment: it worked m8 thanks alot:) to export now i should output the database file to this path "/data/data/com.myapp.main/databases/MYDB"?

Comment: Go to your installed android path `"\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools"` and through command prompt run: `adb pull mnt/sdcard/MYDB` where MYDB is the name of your database.

Comment: i made it work. I rewrite the same code and changed the roles. I read from sd and write to the datrabase location and it works. ty for the reply anw man and for your help

Answer (score 0):

Above accepted answer will not work for Android version on or above 6 because database path is different.

please check below code . It will work on all devices.

```
    public static boolean exportDB(Context context) {
    String DATABASE_NAME = "my.db";
    String databasePath = context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).getPath();
    String inFileName = databasePath;
    try {
        File dbFile = new File(inFileName);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(dbFile);

        String outFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + DATABASE_NAME;

        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        //Close the streams
        output.flush();
        output.close();
        fis.close();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```