# how can i see my sqlite database structure in eclipse IDE

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

I create a table in sqlite database I am doing all the CRUD operation but I want to see my database schema . I try through DDMS tool of eclipse IDE but there is no database. How can I see my database.i am using real device. Please Help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You make sure to choose the right emulator or real device in DDMS ?

Comment: i am using real device

Comment: I think can't. If you want, you can try root your device

Comment: You can download [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com) to test.

Comment: can i check without rooting the device

Comment: I think can't if your device don't root. Because OS don't accept it.

Comment: ok thanks for giveing your appriciate time..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this method:

STEP 1: First export the database by writing function :

```
public static void backupDatabase() throws IOException {
    //Open your local db as the input stream
    String inFileName = "/data/data/com.myapp.main/databases/MYDB";
    File dbFile = new File(inFileName);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(dbFile);

    String outFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/MYDB";
    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = fis.read(buffer))>0){
        output.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    //Close the streams
    output.flush();
    output.close();
    fis.close();
}
```

Taken from [Stack overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16537231/3370870)

Then download DB Browser for SQLite and open database file there.[DB Browser for SQLite](http://sqlitebrowser.org/)

And you are good to go.Inform me if you found any difficulties while implementing this.

Comment: hello smit i do this for exporting work but can't understand how to see my database from db brower when i go in file explorer i expends the data folder nothing so ther what can i do.

Comment: Assuming that you have successfully exported db file and opened it on Sqlite browser then just clicked on "browse data" then click on your any of the table name, and if you have any kind of data then it will be displayes here otherwise just blank filed is there.

Comment: but in my file explorer there  is no option for browse data

Comment: @MssiOS Can you please post a screenshot?

Comment: how can i send screen shot can you give mail id

Comment: @MssiOS If you find this ans helpfull then kindly upvote and/or accept it.Thank you

Comment: @MssiOS , You must use DBbrowser see my answer there is a link.

Comment: thanks smit i do this i can see my database structure .thanks once again

Comment: smit can i export my database without doing the above code.

Comment: @MssiOS There is otherkind of database exporting code available on the stackovreflow site, Without using any kind of code your device must be rooted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117066/discussion-between-mss-ios-and-smit-satodia).

Answer (score 0):

In a real device you cannot access the SQLite DB unless ur phone is rooted.. in a virtual device however you can access it. but there is no way u can see the actual schema. all you see is some text files and once you open them up your columns(data fields) are separated by tabs or something. so

> How can I see my database? YOU CAN'T

Answer (score 0):

Only rooted real device can be access using some jar in eclipse.  Other wise you can seed database structure in emulator from DDMS Respective. To know how to do this. 
[Please red this to solve your problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762389/how-to-view-data-saved-in-android-databasesqlite)