# How to get database file on Android

Tags: android, database

In my Android application I want to export my database. But I am not getting the file. Please check the code below.

```
File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
 String  currentDBPath= "/data" +"/data/"+ "com.edsys.eyfs"
                       + "/databases/" + "EdsysEyfsDB";
               Log.d("current path of db", currentDBPath.toString());


File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
               Log.d("backup database", currentDB.toString());
```

I am checking in android emulator. I am not getting any message on "backup database" log. Please help me to find solution for this

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What exactly are you asking. Also, you can retrieve the full database path with *File db= context.getDatabasePath("Databasename.db");*

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/6542214/2065418.
Explain how to import/export database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get the db path like that

```
File dbFile=getDatabasePath("database.db");
 Log.v(TAG, "Db path is: "+dbFile)
```

Comment: Thnx, I get the path. But how to copy that file to another folder