# Can't import SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite, file, import

I have an SQLite databese which succesfully imports/exports by my app to my oldie Samsung Galaxy S (i can see the file from my computer).

But when i try same with samsung tablet (GT-P7500) it gives me an error:

```
java.io.filenotfoundexception: /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/package...: open failed, no such file or directory.
```

I am using import export function from here(the second answer): [Simple export and import of a SQLite database on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6540906/android-simple-export-and-import-of-sqlite-database/6542214#6542214)

So what is wrong, (a gave permisions of reading and writing in manifest)

Comment: have you checked if your sqlite file is in that directory?

Comment: SQL exist, but tablet has no external SD card (it has 16GB internal memory)
Also my SGS1 has no external SD card but it creates file in my specified dir

Comment: The problem is your hardcoded path: `/mnt/sdcard/...` many devices use the internal storage, which can have a different logical name (i.e.: internal, card_00, storage_0, ...)

Comment: My path is not hardcoded. It looks like this  "/Android/data/com.mypr/Notes/listManager"