# Get query from a file text and insert to a database table

Tags: java, android, mysql

I have a text file in which I have stored a list of aliments ,quantity, and calories separated by "==" from the quantity and by "===" from the calories , this is an example:

File aliments.txt

```
Funghi Trifolati_ING == 200 G === 50
Funghi Trifolati_ING == 50 G === 12
Funghi Tritati_ING == 0 === 25
Funghi Tritati_ING == 100 G === 25
Funghi_ING == 0 === 25
Funghi_ING == 1 Cucchiaio === 10
Funghi_ING == 1 Manciata === 10
```

How I can put aliments, quantity, and calories in three different column of a table?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of table ?

You should you [split](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) to split your String in substrings.

```
String[] alimentAndRest = unsplitString.split("==");
String aliment = alimentAndRest[0];
String[] quantityAndCalories = alimentAndRest[1].split("===");
String quantity = quantityAndCalories[0];
String calories = quantityAndCalories[1];
```

Comment: ok, now I put the database in the asset folder, how I can retreive data?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6540906/simple-export-and-import-of-a-sqlite-database-on-android

Comment: ok , thank you, but I don't understand how to retreive unsplitstring from my db file, can you help me please?