# how to dynamically create SQLite database in external folder?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to create the SQLite database of my app in an external seperate folder dynamically.Is there any way to achieve it? Please share your ideas with a code for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Whatsapp doesn't store database in SDCard, that is everyday or time interveled backup of database.

However you can also take backup of your application database.Refer this [Simple export and import of a SQLite database on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6540906/simple-export-and-import-of-a-sqlite-database-on-android)