# Android SQLite app, preparing for production

Tags: android, database, sqlite, release

I have an Android app where I use a SQLIte DataBase. I am using the app and the DB is already big. Now I want to give this app with its DB to my coworkers. Where and How to put the DB for release? I have the DB in my phone but I need it in assets folder. I was trying but it doesn't work. I tried to copy the DB directly however I read that Android compress files in that folder. Please, any solution, thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15025308/1055954) SO answer? You would just need to get the path to your db file and export it to your sd card or anywhere you'd like.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/sanathp/DatabaseManager_For_Android) is another useful tool. You could modify it a bit to export your db to a specified folder/directory

Answer (score 1):

http://blog.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

Visit this link. It contains the easiest and well described answer for your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use emulator Like GenyMotion and any other emulator. Run your app on emulator then just go to Android Studio->Tools->Android Device Monitor Then select the emulator and in the file Explorer you can find your db file . and then export from the device and export to your desktop. here you can give it to any one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own SQLite database by adding it to assets folder. The best way is to use [Android SQLiteAssetHelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper). Better than reinventing the wheel.

Here the excerpts from its readme:

> An Android helper class to manage database creation and version
>   management using an application's raw asset files.
>
> This class provides developers with a simple way to ship their Android
>   app with an existing SQLite database (which may be pre-populated with
>   data) and to manage its initial creation and any upgrades required
>   with subsequent version releases.
>
> It is implemented as an extension to SQLiteOpenHelper, providing an
>   efficient way for ContentProvider implementations to defer opening and
>   upgrading the database until first use.
>
> Rather than implementing the onCreate() and onUpgrade() methods to
>   execute a bunch of SQL statements, developers simply include
>   appropriately named file assets in their project's assets directory.
>   These will include the initial SQLite database file for creation and
>   optionally any SQL upgrade scripts.