# Can I export my sqlite database from Flutter?

Tags: android, sqlite, flutter

There are various articles on how to import data on the internal database from a csv, from another database etc .. but I haven't found anyone explaining how to export the flutter database.

The goal is to create a backup for each cell phone.
(So I need to understand where it is located for create a backup)

Comment: Are you using the flutter package sqflite ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I use

Answer (score 5):

I assume you are using `sqflite` plugin for SQLite operations and `path_provider` for storage. The path of the database can be found using

```
String path = await getDatabasesPath(); // which is data/data/<package_name>/databases
```

Additionally, `sqflite` plugin doesn't provide any way to import/export database, here is an open [issue](https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/issues/189), if you really want to do it, you will have to do it natively using `MethodChannel`, here is the solution for [Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6540906/simple-export-and-import-of-a-sqlite-database-on-android) and AFAIK there is no way to do it in iOS.

Comment: Ok, but for ios is there a solution? Obviously always natively

Comment: @AlexPad I don't think there exist any solution for iOS.

Comment: @AlexPad I tested the method, it works both for iOS(emulator) and Android(emulator).

Answer (score 4):

if you use Sqlite to create database:

Step 1: When you create database, you set a directory for it, you can use path_provider like this:

```
var dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
_dbPath = dir.path + '/$dbName';
```

so now you know what directory and path it is.

Step 2: Then use `flutter_archive` plugin to zip the file (This will zip the file in a directory, which is your db);

Step 3: use flutter_email_sender to send it by email, like this:

```
final email = Email(
      body: 'content',
      subject: 'content',
      recipients: ['email'],
      cc: ['email'],
      attachmentPaths: [exportPath],
      isHTML: false,
    );
    await FlutterEmailSender.send(email);
```

Your need to provide `exportPath`, which is the zip file path you set up.

It worked for us, hope this will help other people!

Comment: Actually when your database is open, you can not archive it I think and you need to close the database first which is a bit challenging like how you can do it when you is still running?

Answer (score 0):

Usually on Android, databases are stored at 
   /data/data/your.app.signature.here/databases/. 
But I don't know if that's different on flutter apps.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

**dependencies:**

```
 sqflite: ^2.0.0+3
 path_provider: ^2.0.11
 permission_handler: ^10.0.0
```

## **Export ( back up)**

To export SQFLite database , I came across some errors , some of the error are

1. FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path
2. error: permission denied, errno = 13
3. etc........

I want to export my **Database** into **Download** folder that is ,

this is my Database path **/data/user/0/com.example.reminder_app/databases/notes.db** , it's a application directory path so my aim is to export **notes.db** file into this path
**/storage/emulated/0/Download/**

1. Expanding **dBToCopy** functions , this function will give path of **Database**

```
  Future<File> dBToCopy() async {
    final db = await instance.database;
    final dbPath = await getDatabasesPath();
    var afile = File(dbPath);
    return afile;
  }
```

2. full code bellow

```
dbExportToDownloadFolder() async {

 File result = await NotesDatabase.instance.dBToCopy();
 print("lllllllllllllllllll ${result.absolute.path}"); 
        
 Directory documentsDirectory = 
           Directory("storage/emulated/0/Download/");

 String newPath = join(documentsDirectory.absolute.path + 'abcde.db');

 File b = 
      File("/data/user/0/com.example.reminder_app/databases/notes.db");
                         
 if ( await Permission.storage.request().isGranted &&
      await Permission.accessMediaLocation.request().isGranted &&
      await Permission.manageExternalStorage.request().isGranted )
       {
         File a = await b.copy(newPath);
        } else {
             print("No Permission Granted");
               }
}
```

**Note**

```
File result = await NotesDatabase.instance.dBToCopy();

print("lllllllllllllllllll ${result.absolute.path}");
```

**OutPut print**

> lllllllllllllllllll /data/user/0/com.example.reminder_app/databases

this **result** file not contain the **notes.db** file , only contain this path
**/data/user/0/com.example.reminder_app/databases**

To get the **DatabaseFile**

```
File b = File("/data/user/0/com.example.reminder_app/databases/notes.db");

                or 

File b = File("${result.path}"+"/notes.db");
```

so using the file **b** we can copy the file to Download folder file that is **abcde.db**

To do that create a file in **Download** , that is **abcde.db**

```
 Directory documentsDirectory = Directory("storage/emulated/0/Download/");

 String newPath = join(documentsDirectory.absolute.path + 'abcde.db');
```

and using the **copy** method , to copy one file to another file

```
 File a = await b.copy(newPath);
```

**Note**

If you are getting permission denied errors and **OS** errors please add all permission in **manifest** , and using **permission_handler** allow all permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION"/>
```

after the copying , A new file created in **Download** folder that is **abcde.db**