# Android - Can not find the file although it exists in the data folder?

Tags: android, file, copy, file-not-found

I am trying to copy the SQLite database from the data folder to SDCard using Emulator, i am using below code, which i found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995320/how-to-backup-database-file-to-sdcard-on-android/2661882#2661882).

```
try {
    File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

    if (sd.canWrite()) {
        String currentDBPath = "\\data\\PackageName\\databases\\myDB.db";
        String backupDBPath = "myDB.db";
        File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
        File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

        if (currentDB.exists()) 
        {
           // code to copy from currentDB  to backupDB 
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

For write permission below is also added to manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

**Issue**:

**The issue is that the "currentDB.exists()" returns FALSE**.

The "currentDB.getAbsolutePath()" returns the path which is "data\data\PackageName\databases\myDB.db"

This is the correct location of the database, because i can find it using Eclipse >> DDMS perspective >> File Explorer

Can somebody help me find the issue why the "currentDB.exists()" returns FALSE?

Thanks for your valuable time & help.

Comment: Surely you substitute `PackageName` with you real app package name, don't you?

Comment: @Arhimed: Yes, i have replaced it with the real app package name

Comment: Are you sure `currentDB.exists()` is returning false and there isn't some sort of other logic error?  I have the exact same code in my application...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well guys i just removed the "**.db**" extension & it works now!
See the updated code below:

```
try 
 {
    File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

    if (sd.canWrite()) {
        String currentDBPath = "\\data\\PackageName\\databases\\myDB";
        String backupDBPath = "myDB";
        File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
        File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

        if (currentDB.exists()) 
        {
           // code to copy from currentDB  to backupDB 
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

myDB.db is replaced with "**myDB**".

Comment: It's because you didn't name your DB with the .db extension.  You should (for future reference) have a static constant with your DB name somewhere and reference it with `Main.DATABASE_NAME`.  Then you'll need `String currentDBPath = "\\data\\PackageName\\databases\\" + Main.DATABASE_NAME`.  This will prevent similar problems.