# No such file or directory but in fact path seems to be correct

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to export an sqlite database to the sdcard. When I test the application (both on real device and on emulator) I get an error regarding the path of my database. When I check from the DDMS the path of the database it seems to be the one that is printed as not found.

```
File dbFile =
            new File(Environment.getDataDirectory() + "/data/"+c.getPackageName()+"/databases/myDB.db");
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I used the code found here:
[Making a database backup to SDCard on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814213/making-a-database-backup-to-sdcard-on-android)

Comment: why don't you use `SQLiteOpenHelper` ? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db

Comment: I had a similar problem (or two) with an app I was programming. On the device the trouble I was having (with a simple file, actually) was that I hadn't declared I/O in the manifest. In my operating system (Windows 7) the trouble was that Eclipse didn't have permissions to create/read files (I solved it by running Eclipse with Admin privileges)

Comment: my database actually extends SQLiteHelper

Comment: I have the permission shown above. isnt it enough?

Comment: Even running Eclipse with Admin Privileges, does not find the file

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8141330/android-can-not-find-the-file-although-it-exists-in-the-data-folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, don't use hardcoded paths for anything in Android - they're not guaranteed to be the same across all devices.

Try using `getDatabasePath("myDB.db").getAbsolutePath();`

Comment: this actually produces the wrong path... 01-26 00:00:59.744: E/mypck(403): /data/data/com.android.myapp/databases/myDB.db/myDB.db (No such file or directory)

Comment: @JustCurious: Sorry, my bad. Don't add the database name onto the end - I was thinking of a different API. Look at my answer again, I've edited the command to use.

Comment: for the emulator, it worked with just altering the db name to "myDB" without the extension .db

Answer (score 0):

This problem is commonly caused by incorrectly starting an activity.
Activities (except the first) have to be called by intents. Starting an activity using something like

```
Activity a = new ActivityExample();
```

will cause this error to be thrown on all file system access calls

Comment: Can you elaborate please? I am using an AsyncTask here which is called from an Activity which  is called from Main Activity using startActivity(intent);

Comment: @JustCurious Ah never mind then that wouldn't cause this error