# Export Android SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I have created a database for my application. Now I want to make sure that all the attributes are correct and rows are getting filled properly. Database seems to be in `/data` folder but this folder seems to be empty. When I try to use sqlite3 to access it (from the command line using `adb shell` ) I get a not found error. The android phone that I am playing around is a Google Nexus S.   Any ideas on how to export it or test that the database is build correctly and used as intended?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the DDMS perspective use the file explorer while an emulator is running. You can explore the folders there. You will find your database in /data/data/your-package-name/databases
You can find details about DDMS [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/ddms.html)

Comment: Please look at the following link, step by step procedure with images, same as @C.d wrote.
http://www.weston-fl.com/blog/?p=2812

Comment: This will only work if your device is rooted - emulators are rooted by default. In many of the devices you will not have access to /data/data to do what you are suggesting.

Answer (score 4):

You might find this question helpful:

[How do I backup a database file to the SD card on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995320/how-to-backup-database-file-to-sdcard-on-android)

@skeniver says:

```
try {
    File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

    if (sd.canWrite()) {
        String currentDBPath = "//data//{package name}//databases//{database name}";
        String backupDBPath = "{database name}";
        File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
        File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

        if (currentDB.exists()) {
            FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
            FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
            dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
            src.close();
            dst.close();
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

with @Jakobud adding that you need to have the

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

in your manifest.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to either root your phone, or else use the emulator. On normal non-rooted phones, you don't have permission to access private app data like this.

[Read this to see how to export your file for analysis](http://www.weston-fl.com/blog/?p=2812).

Comment: At some point either way I will have to get the tables of the database as I will have to perform a data analysis on them. There should be a way of getting those data. As for now, how can I access those data from emulator?

Comment: See C.d.'s answer for details on how to browse the emulator's filesystem from Eclipse/DDMS.

Comment: Thanks! How about when I will have to export it for data analysis? I will need to export many databases then.

Comment: Added link to my answer telling you how to export the data.

Comment: Your link just point to your whole web site. Please consider pointing to the article instead of the whole web site.