# How to view sqlite database in android application at run time

Tags: android, adb

I am trying to copy data from `DDBMS perspective -> file explorer -> data -> [my_app_package]` then `PULL` this is working when I am running application on emulator but when I am running application on mobile nothing is shown under data folder.

I have also tried to do same thing from adb but its not working.. Is their any way to explore sqllite database created by my application without rooting my phone.

Comment: if your Phone is rooted than i have one tool that you can edit any DB runtime

Comment: 1. You don't have permissions to see the application data in a non rooted phone.
2. You have to create a copy of your existing database in a folder and then access it. (Vikalp Patel has given a working example below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can surely retreive database `.db` file from Android Device programmatically. I used to put one more setting under my application named `Developer Options` which copy `.db` file into `sdCard`.

Following code copy `.db` to `sdcard`. Change your copied `.db` file name into whatever like to with `backupDBPath` and `currentDBPath (Name which you gave to your database name)`.

```
public void dev()
    {
        try {
            File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

            if (sd.canWrite()) {
                String currentDBPath = "/data/data/" + getPackageName() + "/databases/ZnameDB";
                String backupDBPath = "ZnameDB_Dev.db";
                File currentDB = new File(currentDBPath);
                File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

                if (currentDB.exists()) {
                    FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                    FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                    dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                    src.close();
                    dst.close();
                    Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Database Transfered!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
        }
  }
```

There are many application available in `PlayStore` with which you can view your `.db` file. I used [aSQLiteManager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.andsen.asqlitemanager) android application to view `.db` file.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't,how ever  you can use `logs` to fetch and see the fetched data in `logcat` or set some value on your `textviews` or use `table layout` too see your fetched data .However the best way is using `SQLiteBrowser`.You can **pull the database file from your emulator or device and then save it on your hard disk and browse it in Sqlitebrowser.**

- Download SqliteBrowser from here http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/

Answer (score 0):

You can copy your sqlite file to sdcard programmatically. Follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12489718/how-can-i-backup-sqlite-file-in-sd-card-programmatically). And view it using any Sqlite Viewer.