# Database not created (file cannot be found) in SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I created a database named as memberInfo.db in android studio. but the file cannot be found in the device file explorer. I am using android studio 3.1.3. I attached a image of my device file explorer.

[image]

DBHelper.java class

```
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "memberInfo.db";

public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES = "CREATE TABLE " +
            MembersMaster.Members.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
            MembersMaster.Members.COLUMN_NAME_MEMBER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            MembersMaster.Members.COLUMN_NAME_FULLNAME + " TEXT," +
            MembersMaster.Members.COLUMN_NAME__ADDRESS + " TEXT," +
            MembersMaster.Members.COLUMN_NAME__PHONE + " TEXT," +
            MembersMaster.Members.COLUMN_NAME__EMAIL + "TEXT," +
            MembersMaster.Members.COLUMN_NAME__BIRTHDATE + "TEXT)";

            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);

}


@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

}
}
```

MembersMaster.java class

```
package com.heisenberg.librarywiz;

import android.provider.BaseColumns;

public final class MembersMaster {

private MembersMaster() {};

public static class Members implements BaseColumns{

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "members";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_MEMBER_ID = "memId";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_FULLNAME = "fullname";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME__ADDRESS ="address";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME__PHONE ="phone";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME__EMAIL ="email";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME__BIRTHDATE ="birthdate";

}

}
```

Comment: Check This Answer, Please: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25073256/6444297

Answer (score 0):

try this in SQL_CREATE_ENTIRES:

```
String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES = "CREATE TABLE " +
        MembersMaster.Members.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
        MembersMaster.Members.COLUMN_NAME_MEMBER_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        MembersMaster.Members.COLUMN_NAME_FULLNAME + " TEXT, " +
        MembersMaster.Members.COLUMN_NAME__ADDRESS + " TEXT, " +
        MembersMaster.Members.COLUMN_NAME__PHONE + " TEXT, " +
        MembersMaster.Members.COLUMN_NAME__EMAIL + "TEXT, " +
        MembersMaster.Members.COLUMN_NAME__BIRTHDATE + "TEXT);";
```

You left semicolon at the end of expression.

Another tip:

```
public static class Members implements BaseColumns{

public static final String TABLE_NAME = "members";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_MEMBER_ID = BaseColumns._ID; // if you implement BaseColumns, the table IS should use this
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_FULLNAME = "fullname";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME__ADDRESS ="address";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME__PHONE ="phone";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME__EMAIL ="email";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME__BIRTHDATE ="birthdate";
```

}

For db name try to use only lowercase letters like "member_info.db".
The db should be created in the following directory:
**/data/data/your_package_name/databases/member_info.db**
Please let me know if it works (or not...)

Comment: it does not fix the issue...still no database file found...anyway thank you

Comment: still no file found.. i cheked in device file explorer -> data -> app -> myprojectpackagename -> android -> databse folder. And In the path menthioned by you it says "run-as: Package 'myPackageName' is unknown' "...please take a look...thank you

Comment: Not explorer -> data -> app ... but _explorer->data->data->myprojectpackage->databases_ folder! And one more thing: **unless you don't call at least one time 'dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();' or another DBHelper method from your Activity, your database won't be created**!