# How to backup sqlite database on internal storage

Tags: android, android-intent, android-sdcard, android-sqlite

I am using this below code to copy my database to internal storage but it is not helping me out and always getting this error. I have gone through lots of questions and answers and tried lots of blog posts but am unable to make it work. My phone is **HTC One X**

I have also added one permission in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />



public static boolean backUpDataBase(Context context)
    {
        String packageName = "com.projectWork.mobile";
        try {
            File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

            if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(sd))
            {
                String currentDBPath = "//data//"+ packageName +"//databases//"+"appDb.db";
                String backupDBPath = "appDb.db";
                File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
                File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

                FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                src.close();
                dst.close();
                Toast.makeText(context, backupDB.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

            Toast.makeText(context, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }

        return true;
    }
```

This is the error I am getting

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/appDb.db: open failed:
>   EROFS (Read-only file system)

Please guide as I want to store all my errors in the database so that we can Analyse them later.

Thanks

Comment: why the double '//' ? the error comes from your sdcard being mounted read only, it would seem. I'm not sure about that FileChannel thing. maybe plain fileinput/outputstream would work better ?

Comment: you are right, the problem comes when I try to write the file in the sd card then it says readonly error. ...please suggest. My mobile is not rooted and I don't want to do that either

Comment: start by trying to create a file a write to it simply on the sdcard. it may be something stupid like the sdcard is locked.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way. It work in my side.

```
String currentDBPath = "\\data\\"+ packageName +"\\databases\\"+"appDb.db";
```

Also Follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995320/how-to-backup-database-file-to-sdcard-on-android)

Thanks.

Comment: NEVER use a static path like that. Use `context.getDatabasePath(DataBaseHelper.dbName)` instead.