# How to see my application database?

Tags: android, sqlite

I  use Samsung galaxy S2 for debugging. How can I see my database that create by my application.

I can't find by this way

`Eclipse Go To Window > Showview > Other.. > File Expolrer` Click On Open

Now browse To

```
data/data/your.package.name/databases/<DATABASE
```

FILE Here >

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995320/how-to-backup-database-file-to-sdcard-on-android

Comment: root your device or copy your database into sdcard. after that show using sqlitemanager android app

Answer (score 2):

While you are debuging go to the DDMS tab. (With a virtual device, not with your phone)

Then search  /sdcard/your aplication name/databases

** You have to configurate your AVD 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you use emulator then go on DDMS and select device emulator then go file explore data>data>package name>database folder>.db file.

this file your database select this file and pope on any drive and open on SQLite browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can only see the database on a rooted device. So root the device or just use an emulator instance, because the emulator is rooted by default.

Answer (score 0):

You have to `root` your `Device` to see the `database` of your `Applications`.

Comment: this is supposed to be a comment

Comment: @thepoosh seems like an answer to me.user1480210 said there is no database files visible. rickky said that it has to be rooted. Its a solution and answers the question.

Comment: @thepoosh is there any specific reason kindly provide me.

Comment: @JohnWillemse am i asking for any clarification or request from the author ????here in my answer.

Comment: @rickky You're right, I'm sorry, I removed the flag. Somehow I read it as a question, but it's an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it only if your device is rooted.

```
$ adb shell # open adb shell
$ su        # ask for superuser rights
$ cat /data/data/your.package.name/databases/database_name >> /sdcard/Download/database_name  # copy database file to a folder where you don't need root access to get it from device to PC
$ exit      # close adb shell
$ adb pull /sdcard/Download/database_name # get that copied file
```

Now you can browser via editor, such as [sqlitebrowser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/)

```
$ sqlitebrowser database_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access app's database ONLY IF your device is rooted!

1). Find DDMS icon in the right-top of Eclipse IDE.

2). Click "File Explorer" tag.

3). Open in order :"data--> data--> your package name-->databases".

4). Select the database you want to check and click "pull a file from the device"button in the tool bar.

5).Browse sqlite database use [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see database. The way you did is correct but if your device is not root, you can not see.
But I think you can run app on Emulator and:
Eclipse Go To Window > Showview > Other.. > File Expolrer Click On Open.

```
There are 2 ways:
1. Root your device
2. Looking for it on emulator
```

Answer (score 0):

**I'm doing this with non-rooted device.** 
 yes, it's really not a very short way but the only way I found, and if you have a big database that you want to be able to make queries and to explore it- that is comfortable way (on non rooted device) :

- send your db file via e-mail to your pc
- use [sqlBrowser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/)

now you can navigate your tables and exec sql queries on the data from your pc.

hope it will help somebody.