# Read/Access SQLite Database on Real Device without Root (Eclipse)

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I been working on my project for a little bit while, I currently using emulator to access the DB I created. However, I wonder if anyone knows a way to access DB on a real device in DDMS eclipse?

I understand that to access DB on emulator is just open the data/data/package_name/database...I couldn't really find a way to check out DB on my real device. (The is some security issue in android device) The reason I want to use this is sometimes, emulator doesn't support GPS signal. Does any one knows is there any third-party lib/plugin I can download from ? Thank you so much.

Comment: There's a method to export a sqlite database and save it as a file in your directory in a real device.

Comment: You really need to copy the DB to somewhere public (prolly SD card). [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995320/how-to-backup-database-file-to-sdcard-on-android) handles that case.

Comment: you can access your application database only(if unrooted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think it is work for you
**I am copy database in  SdCard then access ** .

it is my database helper class

```
public class OpenDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDB";
.
.
.
public OpenDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        // super(context, name, factory, version);
        super(context, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator + "/DataBase/" + File.separator
                + DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
.
.
.
}
```

create object in Activity class

```
OpenDatabaseHelper db = new OpenDatabaseHelper(YourActivity.this);
```

**call any method of database**

```
db.DataBasemethod();
```

**then put this code**

```
try {
            String destPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            File f = new File(destPath);
            if (!f.exists()) {
                f.mkdirs();
                f.createNewFile();
                // ---copy the db from the /data/data/ folder into
                // the sdcard databases folder--- here MyDB is database name
                CopyDB(new FileInputStream("/data/data/" + getPackageName()+ "/databases"), new FileOutputStream(destPath+ "/MyDB"));
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

public void CopyDB(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream)
            throws IOException {
        // ---copy 1K bytes at a time---
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();
    }
```

Comment: What did you mean by `copy database in SdCard then access`?